# Is cell value on other tabs?

Tags: google-sheets, tabs, formula

In sheets I have a workbook with several tabs. I need to be able to determine if the value in column A is found on other tabs to hopefully eliminate duplicates.

How can I put a formula on each tab that will point out if the value in column A is found on other tabs so we can remove duplicates? The formula would need to have the name of tab to enable us to go through and cleanup?

I know in Excel we could do a vlookup for each individual tab but it seems like there should be an easier way of not having to type the vlookup for each tab and return the name of the tab.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts a s is suggested in [ask]. Also include if you are looking for formula or script based solution.

Comment: You can include several tabs into one `vlookup` formula as specified [here](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/vlookup-across-different-sheet-tabs-in-google-sheets/), but if you want to do it dynamically without knowing in advance how many tabs you have / what their names are - you would need to write a [script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).